# Transaction Management for Spring data cassandra

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring and Cassandra as the underlying database. Had referred to the spring umbrella project 'spring data cassandra'. 
Could not find out how transactions are managed here unlike hibernate.
Kindly share the details for the Transaction Manager to be included if some of you have incorporated the same.

Answer (score 5):

Cassandra does not support transactions in the traditional (ACID) sense. There are a few constructs where you can achieve something like transactional atomicity in special cases, like atomic batches (see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/atomic-batches-in-cassandra-1-2) or Lightweight Transactions (see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0), but nothing that lends itself to a full-blown transaction management.

This is mostly the result of the architecture of Cassandra, which focuses on scalability and fault tolerance on a level not possible with traditional relational databases.

Comment: I know that Cassandra does not support Transaction atomicity.I'm trying to figure out if there is some framework which would carry out the task for me.Kundera(https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Transaction-Management) seems to do the work but I'm looking something specific with Spring-data-cassandra project(http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/)

Comment: Sorry, @Anish, nothing like that in SDC.  Feel free to create an issue requesting it at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS

Comment: @Mathew Adams : I logged the same in JIRA but they marked it as Invalid. They have misinterpreted as Cassandra issue and not something which can be incorporated by creating a wrapper by Spring instead on top of Cassandra. You can find my bug logged [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-180)

Answer (score 5):

Cassandra batch is currently atomic by default.
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html

So it is , probably, the best equivalent to @Transactional in spring data
(Although, full ACID is not for this world, it is just not that way it plays)

Something like this should play(YOU can change values of ConsistencyLevel and RetryPolicy as you wish - that is the matter!):

```
Insert insert1 = CassandraTemplate.createInsertQuery("table1", value1, new WriteOptions(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE, RetryPolicy.DEFAULT), cassandraConverter);

Insert insert2 = CassandraTemplate.createInsertQuery("table2", value2, new WriteOptions(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE, RetryPolicy.DEFAULT), cassandraConverter);

Batch batch = QueryBuilder.batch(insert1,insert2);

//cassandraOperations - object of CassandraTemplate , injected by Spring
cassandraOperations.execute(batch);
```